Sphinx PDF build failing on readthedocs for Russian translation
PDF builds of Sphinx's own documentation are failing for Russian translation (example build). .readthedocs.yml is set to build HTML and then PDF, and it is in the second step the failure arises. I haven't set any Russian specific setting (should I?)
The following error reported is:

Build output directory contains multiple files
Build output directory for format "pdf" contains multiple files and it is not currently supported. Please, remove all the files but the "pdf" you want to upload."

but the build log (see raw log of the above link) contains other outputs I don't understand it and don't know how to debug it.

Read the Docs supports only one PDF file. Make sure there is one and only one PDF file at $READTHEDOCS_OUTPUT/pdf before finishing the build.
